# Find file by (similar) name PHP

Tags: php, file, search, glob

I have a folder with songs, and the names of the files are: "Singer - Song"

I have a file with this name: "Example - A test song"

I want to find that file when I search for:

"Eample - A test song"

"Example - test song"

"eximple - A teste song"

Even if the search name has some errors, I want to find that file.
How can I do it?

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Comment: I tried searching for the glob... but I don't think it works, I tried:

`glob("*[Exmple]*-*[Test song]*.mp3");`

But it finds every file that the name is "some words - some words"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a short script by using PHP's [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/de/function.similar-text.php) function. It works for all strings written above.

```
<?php
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$needle = "eximple - A teste song";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            similar_text($file, $needle, $percent);
            if($percent > 80)
                echo $file  . " similarity: " . $percent . "<br />";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Explanation: The function calculates how much the two strings `$file` and `$needle` match (in percent). If they match more than 80% the file name is echoed. Feel free to adjust `$needle` and `$dir` to suit your needs.

Comment: I tried it, and it works great! Thats exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this... Assuming you want the song names to pop up while typing I would say you need a live search feature.

I used w3 when I was creating mine and it worked wonderfully.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: I don't need live search, but I will see if I can use something from the live search and use it for my problem. Thanks